# Laravel Queue not running the actual job

Tags: laravel

I'm facing an issue in my production environment. One specific job is not working as expected when specifically called via the scheduler `php artisan schedule:run`. As it seems, the queue worker does not run through the code in the `handle` function of the job. Instead, the job is marked as completed in Horizon. The strange thing is that if I run Laravel Tinker on my production server, and push the job manually to the queue it works as expected.

See below for my setup and code snippets.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue is? No code around this specific job has been touched in months, and the issue just showed up randomly last Friday. The server, docker, and Horizon have been restarted several times without any change in the behavior.

**Server Setup**

```
Laravel Version: v8.78.1

Laravel Horizon Version: v5.7.18

Docker PHP Image: php:8.1.0-fpm-alpine3.15
```

**App\Console\Kernel.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new AdExportFile(
            fileName: 'adwords.csv',
            daysToExport: 10,
            header: [
                'Google Click ID',
                'Conversion Name',
                'Conversion Time',
                'Conversion Value',
                'Conversion Currency'
            ],
            timezone: config('app.timezone'),
            origin: Visit::SOURCE_GOOGLE
        ))->hourly();
}
```

**App\Jobs\AdExportFile.php**

```
class AdExportFile implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;

    public const QUEUE = 'default';

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(
        protected string $fileName,
        protected int $daysToExport,
        protected array $header,
        protected string $timezone,
        protected string $origin,
        protected string $delimiter = ',',
        protected int $minBaseCommission = 5000
    ) {
        $this->onQueue(static::QUEUE);
        \Log::info('AdExportFile: Running __construct');
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::info('AdExportFile: Running the handle function');
    }
}
```

**Log output**

```
AdExportFile: Running __construct
```

Edit: This has now spread to a second job, that is called via the "$schedule->call" method

Comment: how you configure your queue driver? if its not `"sync"` then you need to configure properly to let everything works, please read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#driver-prerequisites

Comment: Seeing we are running Laravel Horizon, we have the driver as Redis. The queue driver works fine, all other jobs which run once an hour works, and on top of that we have several hundred jobs running each hour without issue. So the unknown issue is only for this job for some reason.

Comment: can you seed this job from the horizon dashboard?

Comment: Yes, they always show up as completed. And the run time is always under a second, eg, 0.011 seconds. See following image, https://imgur.com/9toQYez

Comment: it seems like you have separated instance to handle the queue, the `handle()` is running in different instance so the log probably is in that instance also

Comment: The log is nowhere to be found. I use papertrail, and it is not in there nor in the server logs. For the example, I have removed the logic we use, and if handle was called we would notice it by seeing a log, seeing a file gets uploaded to Azure and the job run time is more than a second. The job should take 5-7 seconds if the handle function was run, but it is not. As stated above the job finishes in 0.011 seconds, which is impossible.

Comment: have you try restart the queue worker/horizon? if there is an older version of this class running, the new code will not applied until you restart

Comment: As stated on OP everything has been restarted. Other changes have gone live, but it's this specific thing that is not working.